# How do I read the PAN from an EMV SmartCard from Java

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, emv

I need to read account number from Maestro/Mastercard with smart card reader. I am using Java 1.6 and its javax.smartcardio package. I need to send APDU command which will ask EMV application stored on card's chip for PAN number. Problem is, I cannot find regular byte array to construct APDU command which will return needed data anywhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to wrap the APDU further. The API layer should take care of that.

It looks like the 0x6D00 response just means that the application did not support the INS.

Just troubleshooting now, but you did start out by selecting the MasterCard application, right?

I.e. something like this:

```
void selectApplication(CardChannel channel) throws CardException {
  byte[] masterCardRid = new byte[]{0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04};
  CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, masterCardRid);
  ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
  return response.getData();
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite understand your answer. my response always hit 0x6D00. what should I do if my card doesn't support INS just like you said ?

Answer (score 4):

here is some working example:

```
CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel(); 

 byte[] selectMaestro={(byte)0x00, (byte)0xA4,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x07 ,(byte)0xA0 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x00 ,(byte)0x04 ,(byte)0x30 ,(byte)0x60 ,(byte)0x00};
  byte[] getProcessingOptions={(byte)0x80,(byte)0xA8,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00};
  byte[] readRecord={(byte)0x00,(byte)0xB2,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x0C,(byte)0x00};

  ResponseAPDU r=null;

   try {
     ATR atr = card.getATR(); //reset kartice

      CommandAPDU capdu=new CommandAPDU( selectMaestro   );

       r=card.getBasicChannel().transmit( capdu );

      capdu=new CommandAPDU(getProcessingOptions);
      r=card.getBasicChannel().transmit( capdu );


      capdu=new CommandAPDU(readRecord);
      r=card.getBasicChannel().transmit( capdu );
```

This works with Maestro card, I can read PAN number, yet now I need to read MasterCard's PAN number. I do not know should I change the read record APDU or select application APDU. Anyone familiar with APDUs?

Comment: It is the select application command you need to change. The last part of that command is the AID of the application you want to select. Changing that to the MasterCard AID should work. Or you might want to just shorten the AID. If you supply A400000004, ...

Comment: ... it should match all AIDs starting with A400000004.

Answer (score 1):

```
atr = open();
prints(atr);

prints("[Step 1] Select 1PAY.SYS.DDF01 to get the PSE directory");
cmd = new ISOSelect(ISOSelect.SELECT_AID, EMV4_1.AID_1PAY_SYS_DDF01);
card_response = execute(cmd);
prints(card_response);
SFI = NumUtil.hex2String((byte)((1 < < 3) | 4));

// try SFI 1 record 1
prints("[Step 2] Send READ RECORD with 0 to find out where the record is");
read = new EMVReadRecord(SFI, "01", "00");
card_response = execute(read);
prints(card_response);
byte_size = NumUtil.hex2String(card_response.getStatusWord().getSw2());

prints("[Step 3] Send READ RECORD with 1C to get the PSE data");
read = new EMVReadRecord(SFI, "01", byte_size);
card_response = execute(read);
prints(card_response);
// the AID is A0000000031010
prints("[Step 4] Now that we know the AID, select the application");

cmd = new ISOSelect(ISOSelect.SELECT_AID, "A0000000031010");
card_response = execute(cmd);
prints(card_response);
prints("[Step 5] Send GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command");

cmd = new EMVGetProcessingOptions();
card_response = execute(cmd);
prints(card_response);

// SFI for the first group of AFL is 0C

prints("[Step 6] Send READ RECORD with 0 to find out where the record is");
read = new EMVReadRecord("0C", "01", "00");
card_response = execute(read);
prints(card_response);
byte_size = NumUtil.hex2String(card_response.getStatusWord().getSw2());

prints("[Step 7] Use READ RECORD with the given number of bytes to retrieve the data");
read = new EMVReadRecord("0C", "01", byte_size);
card_response = execute(read);
prints(card_response);

data = new TLV(card_response.getData());

close();
```

Comment: Hi Grandie, Can you add TLV class here

Answer (score 0):

You need to do construct a CommandAPDU object and pass it to the transmit()-command.

You should be able to find the precise command in the documentation for your smartcard, but here is one example:

```
byte[] readFile(CardChannel channel) throws CardException {
  CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(0xB0, 0x60, 0x10, 0x00);
  ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
  return response.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking up in your documentation what 0x6D00 means? It looks like it might mean that the ENVELOPE command is not supported. Have you tried using T=0 protocol instead of T=1?

I would not expect my example to work on your card. I don't know which APDUs the Maestro/MasterCard-supports, so I couldn't give you a working example.

Try giving the command an explicit expected length like this:

```
byte[] readPan(CardChannel channel) throws CardException {
  CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB2, 0x5a, 0x14, 250);
  ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
  return response.getData();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

what about using a  scanner, getting a picture of the card, scanning the content of the picture with a good java ocr library ( like http://ocr4j.sourceforge.net/ for example ) and search for a (usually) 16 digit sequence XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX , then you will get the PAN from any EMV card using java.