# C# smartcards programming

Tags: c#, smartcard

How should I start to programm in C# (.NET) for smartcards?
For the beginning I just need to know, what is the name of Card Reader (e.g. Omnikey)
and print that out.

Thanks for the answer, Ales.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A while back I had to write what I thought was going to be some simple and easy smartcard code and let me tell you, it was no walk in the park. First of all, it turned out that good information on smartcards is hard to come by on the Net. And when I did find several websites, there was a lot of discussion of the underlying Win32 API calls and a whole bunch of other low-level stuff, which isn't quite easy reading.

The thing is that they're called **smart** cards for a reason. That reason is that you're basically interacting with an embedded microprocessor by sending it commands that it understands and responds to. This can get a bit complicated because many of the manufacturers thought it was a good idea to implement their own commands, so many things are contingent on the type of card that you're using. On top of that there are cards that look like smartcards but aren't really smartcards and don't even use any of the "standard" smartcard interfaces, so you end up using the Windows SmartCard API just to fire up your reader, and the smartcard reader's special API provided as a .lib in some obscure corner of their website for the rest...

Well, I did get my app working eventually but like I said, it wasn't easy. At any rate I made a big mistake by assuming it would not be very difficult to do.

If you really want to get into smartcards I suppose your best bet would be to get a good book on the subject but since I too am little more than a novice, I really can't help you there.

As for websites, the most useful thing in C# terms that I was able to dig up was [A Smartcard Framework for .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/smartcardapi.aspx). Note that this is not the same article as [the one posted by michaelvdnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852233/7487335), although the author is the same. The article I linked to describes a C# wrapper for the native smartcard API, while michaelvdnest's adds XML to the mix, although I don't know exactly in what way because I haven't read it yet.

So start dissecting the code supplied with the article and good luck. If memory serves me, the reader enumeration stuff is pretty easy to find.

Comment: Thank you very much for this long answer :) my coworker already told me that I've a long way to go ... and he couldn't help me either. Well now I know it can be done and thanks for the link, I've found it already and I'm reading and processing it now.

Comment: @sql You're not new to Stackoverflow. Ask a new question.

Comment: You're not kidding about it not being a walk in the park. One of our developers had previously implemented code based on the referenced article so reading the card is not presenting me with a problem but I am struggling to figure out how to do authentication to allow me to read secured data from European digital tachograph cards. Reading the spec is a bit like swimming through mud.

Comment: Having recently picked up the poisoned chalice of having to program a smart card, I can't remember the last time I arrived at work so depressed...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Smart Card Framework for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/SmartcardFmwk.aspx) on Code Project. It describes an XML framework for .NET to program Smart Card applications.

Comment: I've alredy done that, and I'm still working on it. THanks! :)

Comment: This is by the same guy and is newer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET

Answer (score 3):

I know it's way late.....

but

You can get a very easy to use, and free for personal use professional library here:

https://www.smartcard-api.com/

There's also a community (Completely free to use) Smart Card library here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCSC

In recent years I've favored using the Nu-get one rather than the smart card API one, if you need commercial support however the smart card API lib is the best choice.

Once you have that, you then need to start understanding APDU's and how to shuttle them back and forth from card to terminal.

It really is a huge subject to cover, I have code that will read all the common elements on a standard Chip & Pin EMV card unfortunately it was written for a financial services client so I can't give you it, I can explain however some of what you need to undertake to read the card.

For other cards then it's down to the card itself, for example, I have a card reader and blank cards here, and I have some custom data on some of them which only I know how to access, yet still I have some old satellite and travel cards that are different again.

You can get some ideas here:

[How do I read the PAN from an EMV SmartCard from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283251/how-do-i-read-the-pan-from-an-emv-smartcard-from-java)

and there's a lot of info on smart cards in general to be found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160329205518/http://wrankl.de/SCTables/SCTables.html

especially the generic stuff (of which there is some)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on an app in Visual Studio 2015 to read smart cards. What you want to do is get the USB Devices connected to your computer that are Smart Card Readers.  Then iterate through the return for the information your looking for.  While the readers has quite a few properties, here are the ones I chose to use.  I hope this gives you a start in the right direction:

```
static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select *      FROM Win32_PnPEntity where Description Like ""%Smart%card%"""))
            collection = searcher.Get();
        string Device_ID = "";

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
             (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Status")));


            Device_ID = (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID");

        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
```