# Reading Visa payWave Credit Card Details via NFC on Android

Tags: android, credit-card, nfc

Is it possible to read the credit card details (name, number, expiry) of a Visa payWave card via NFC on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus? What about other NFC-enabled credit cards?

If it's not possible, is there some way to retrieve a unique ID from the card?

Also, any references or example code would be a great help.

Answer (score 35):

There are at least 2 Android apps that can already do this: [Squareless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noSquare) and
[Electronic Pickpocket RFID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idstronghold.CCReaderMkt).

Some references:

- Explanation of how to do it: https://saush.wordpress.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/
- Java code: http://code.google.com/p/javaemvreader/
- This may be helpful, too: http://cardpeek.googlecode.com/svn-history/r23/trunk/dot_cardpeek_dir/scripts/emv.lua
- See also this question: [How do I read the PAN from an EMV SmartCard from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283251/how-do-i-read-the-pan-from-an-emv-smartcard-from-java)

Comment: These are great resources for understanding how to read EMV data in Java but they seem to be based on USB/serial card readers. How can EMV data be read on Android via the NFC API? (Obviously, it's possible if the above 2 apps can do it.)

Comment: Example translation of `selectApplication()` in the last [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283251/how-do-i-read-the-pan-from-an-emv-smartcard-from-java) above: `byte[] selectApplication(IsoDep tag) throws IOException {
  byte[] command = new byte[]{0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04};
   return tag.transceive(command);
}`. The `tag` you would get from the NFC `Intent`: `IsoDep tag = IsoDep.get(getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured this out myself but I wasn't really sure, so thanks for the confirmation on this. Some final questions: are the APDU commands/responses used with ISO14443 devices the same as those from ISO7816? Is there a good reference for the ISO14443 APDU commands, aside from buying the docs from ISO?

Comment: Not all ISO 14443-4 devices use ISO 7816-4 APDUs, but quite a few do (such as payment cards).

Answer (score 1):

[Triangle.io](http://www.triangle.io) also has an API that allows you to do this free of charge and you can integrate it in your own application. You can download the sample application from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.triangle.reader.sample&hl=en).

Disclaimer: I work for triangle.io

Comment: Of course it is safe to use :) We use RSA 2048 bit encryption with keys unique to each application and provide only encrypted information. A typical setup our clients use is to send the encrypted information over HTTPS to their back end and decrypt the data there for further processing. This way, no data in the clear is transmitted in the phone internally.

Comment: Your triangle.io initialization procedure suddenly has started to fail in my project. That sucks

Comment: @Bagzerg, there have been no downtimes. Were you having connectivity issues on your end or were you using a trial key that expired? Please use contact@triangle.io to reach out to us so that we can take a look.

Comment: I'm currently using Triangle.io and it's great!