# Is it possible to create your own NFC payment chip?

Tags: android, nfc

The following post details that it is possible to obtain card information from a debit/credit card with a NFC chip:
[Reading Visa payWave Credit Card Details via NFC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648224/reading-visa-paywave-credit-card-details-via-nfc-on-android)

I was wondering if it would be possible to use this card information as a template to create a NFC chip for another card/account that does not have NFC capabilites using a chip/tag such as the below:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/NFC-Tags-NTAG203-Clear-Stickers/dp/B00M5PC0FG/ref=pd_bxgy_ce_img_y

From what I can determine commercial NFC tags are programmable to perform basic tasks, such as directing a NFC enabled device to a stored URL or displaying text.
How does one go about programming a NFC tag to hold card information and enable it to be used as a payment method?
Is this even possibe and if so how difficult would it be to attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible; well, as a user of chip credit cards, I am quite relieved that it can't be done ;)

EMV credit cards only share information with the reader after a mutual authentication procedure, so you wouldn't be able to extract the complete set of data needed to perform a payment transaction. Moreover, even if you were able to copy that information, NFC tags do not have the capabilities to perform the initial authentication.