# How to obtain PAN(Primary Account Number) from a debit/credit smart card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I would like to know how to obtain PAN(Primary Account Number) from a debit/credit smart card.
I try the Maestro debit card using APDU commands and I get the data in bytes, encoded in TLV.
The EMV specification says that PAN is on the tag "A5", but I don't identify it on that tag.

APDU commands:

```
<<00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60
>>61 42

<<00 C0 00 00 42
>>6F 40 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 A5 35 50 07 4D 41 45 53 54 52 4F 87 01 01 5F 2D 06 65 73 65 6E 70 74 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 07 4D 41 45 53 54 52 4F BF 0C 0F 9F 4D 02 0B 0A 9F 6E 07 08 62 00 00 30 30 00 90 00
```

decode data:

```
6F File Control Information (FCI) Template
    84 Dedicated File (DF) Name
        A0000000043060
    A5 File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
        50 Application Label
            M A E S T R O
        87 Application Priority Indicator
            01
        5F2D Language Preference
            e s e n p t
        9F11 Issuer Code Table Index
            01
        9F12 Application Preferred Name
            M A E S T R O
        BF0C File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
            9F4D Log Entry
                0B0A
            9F6E Unknown tag
                08620000303000
90 Issuer Public Key Certificate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read the PAN from an EMV SmartCard from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283251/how-do-i-read-the-pan-from-an-emv-smartcard-from-java)

Comment: The solution is not so simple. I had to read the document: EMV Specifications for Payment Systems, because the data structure is not always the same. 
https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification_20120607062110791.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APDU commands:

```
<<00 B2 01 0C 00
>>6C 89

<<00 B2 01 0C 89
>>70 81 86 9F 42 02 09 37 5F 25 03 17 12 08 5F 24 03 21 12 31 5A 08 XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 5F 34 01 00 9F 07 02 FF C0 8C 27 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 35 01 9F 45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 9F 21 03 9F 7C 14 8D 0C 91 0A 8A 02 95 05 9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 03 01 03 9F 0D 05 B0 50 BC 88 00 9F 0E 05 00 00 00 00 00 9F 0F 05 B0 70 BC 98 00 5F 28 02 08 62 90 00
```

where XX XX... is Application Primary Account Number (PAN), encoded in TLV.

The trick is to know what record to read, where it is, because it is not always in the same place, it depends of the smart card.

sometimes it is `00 B2 01 0C 00` other`00 B2 02 14 00` and other combinations.

recomiendo leer:[Getting information from an EMV chip card with Java](https://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/) and for more details: [EMV Integrated Circuit Card Specifications for Payment Systems Book 3](https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification_20120607062110791.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

PAN can be received in Read Record response.
It is required to get AFL entries after execute GPO (Get Processing Command) command. AFL will describe SFI and record number for which Read Record command need to be executed, After that it is possible to read the PAN from card.

Sample APDUs are:

```html
Command APDU : 00 A4 04 00 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
Response APDU: 6F 15 84 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 03 88 01 01 90 00
Command APDU : 00 B2 01 0C 00
Response APDU: 70 18 61 16 4F 05 A0 00 00 00 00 50 0D 45 4D 56 20 53 69 6D 75 6C 61 74 6F 72 90 00
Command APDU : 00 B2 02 0C 00
Response APDU: 6A 83
Command APDU : 00 A4 04 00 05 A0 00 00 00 00 00
Response APDU: 6F 18 84 05 A0 00 00 00 00 A5 0F 50 0D 45 4D 56 20 53 69 6D 75 6C 61 74 6F 72 90 00
Command APDU : 80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
Response APDU: 77 16 82 02 19 80 94 10 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00 90 00
<-----Read application data as indicated in the Application File Locator.------
---------------------Collect input to data authentication.---------------------
Command APDU : 00 B2 01 0C 00
Response APDU: 70 81 8D 9F 6C 02 00 01 9F 62 06 00 00 00 00 01 C0 9F 63 06 00 00 00 07 80 00 56 4C 42 35 32 33 34 30 30 30 30 35 30 33 34 31 31 34 35 5E 20 2F 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 5E 31 36 30 32 32 30 32 34 39 39 32 30 30 33 39 38 39 31 34 39 38 31 30 30 30 37 34 31 39 36 36 9F 64 01 02 9F 65 02 00 E0 9F 66 02 00 1E 9F 6B 13 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 D1 60 22 02 14 98 10 00 04 00 0F 9F 67 01 02 90 00
Record No. 1
0000  70 81 8D 9F 6C 02 00 01 9F 62 06 00 00 00 00 01  p...l....b......
0010  C0 9F 63 06 00 00 00 07 80 00 56 4C 42 35 32 33  ..c.......VLB523
0020  34 30 30 30 30 35 30 33 34 31 31 34 35 5E 20 2F  4000050341145^ /
0030  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
0040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 5E 31 36 30 32 32 30 32          ^1602202
0050  34 39 39 32 30 30 33 39 38 39 31 34 39 38 31 30  4992003989149810
0060  30 30 37 34 31 39 36 36 9F 64 01 02 9F 65 02 00  00741966.d...e..
0070  E0 9F 66 02 00 1E 9F 6B 13 52 34 00 00 50 34 11  ..f....k.R4..P4.
0080  45 D1 60 22 02 14 98 10 00 04 00 0F 9F 67 01 02  E.`".........g..

Command APDU : 00 B2 01 14 00
Response APDU: 70 81 A3 57 13 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 D1 60 22 01 14 98 19 09 04 00 0F 5A 08 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 5F 24 03 16 02 28 5F 30 02 02 02 9F 44 01 02 5F 28 02 02 80 5F 34 01 04 8C 21 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 35 01 9F 45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 8D 0C 91 0A 8A 02 95 05 9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5E 03 42 03 1F 03 9F 07 02 FF 00 9F 08 02 00 02 9F 0D 05 B4 50 04 00 00 9F 0E 05 00 00 88 00 00 9F 0F 05 B4 70 04 98 00 9F 42 02 09 78 9F 4A 01 82 90 00
Record No. 1
0000  70 81 A3 57 13 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 D1 60 22  p..W.R4..P4.E.`"
0010  01 14 98 19 09 04 00 0F 5A 08 52 34 00 00 50 34  ........Z.R4..P4
0020  11 45 5F 24 03 16 02 28 5F 30 02 02 02 9F 44 01  .E_$...(_0....D.
0030  02 5F 28 02 02 80 5F 34 01 04 8C 21 9F 02 06 9F  ._(..._4...!....
0040  03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37  ......._*......7
0050  04 9F 35 01 9F 45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 8D 0C 91  ..5..E..L..4....
0060  0A 8A 02 95 05 9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0E 00 00 00  ......7..L......
0070  00 00 00 00 00 5E 03 42 03 1F 03 9F 07 02 FF 00  .....^.B........
0080  9F 08 02 00 02 9F 0D 05 B4 50 04 00 00 9F 0E 05  .........P......
0090  00 00 88 00 00 9F 0F 05 B4 70 04 98 00 9F 42 02  .........p....B.
00A0  09 78 9F 4A 01 82                                .x.J..

Command APDU : 00 B2 01 1C 00
Response APDU: 70 81 C0 8F 01 04 9F 32 01 03 92 24 94 EE D1 88 44 B8 C9 0A 55 5C AE 8B 39 16 86 C1 2A 30 ED 71 C2 81 D3 FA 90 EE B0 5E AF 29 8A E2 C9 D1 40 0F 90 81 90 27 18 3B 7E 0B 7D E4 47 D9 C5 2B 5A D9 58 CF 41 60 FD C0 A7 0D 84 C8 8A C9 B0 1B B4 B7 58 61 D8 36 B1 8D 15 4E 28 89 EF 50 CC A8 3E 76 43 B5 27 91 FF 1C C6 1B 1F 0A D6 16 1A F9 E6 8E 14 36 F5 73 07 EC 07 DB B3 04 B6 F1 78 C1 AF 68 3E 3D B7 17 41 32 19 69 95 DB F6 72 1B 13 89 2A CF 46 8A 14 06 60 8E 95 FD 97 7A 3F 34 3D 18 B6 1F 5D 77 E4 E7 9F A0 ED 5A 4B 5D 4B 57 C4 1A 29 E7 B7 FD 1E 9F 42 36 B0 BE ED FF 58 32 C3 6C E0 CF 14 AA 90 00
Record No. 1
0000  70 81 C0 8F 01 04 9F 32 01 03 92 24 94 EE D1 88  p......2...$....
0010  44 B8 C9 0A 55 5C AE 8B 39 16 86 C1 2A 30 ED 71  D...U\..9...*0.q
0020  C2 81 D3 FA 90 EE B0 5E AF 29 8A E2 C9 D1 40 0F  .......^.)....@.
0030  90 81 90 27 18 3B 7E 0B 7D E4 47 D9 C5 2B 5A D9  ...'.;~.}.G..+Z.
0040  58 CF 41 60 FD C0 A7 0D 84 C8 8A C9 B0 1B B4 B7  X.A`............
0050  58 61 D8 36 B1 8D 15 4E 28 89 EF 50 CC A8 3E 76  Xa.6...N(..P..>v
0060  43 B5 27 91 FF 1C C6 1B 1F 0A D6 16 1A F9 E6 8E  C.'.............
0070  14 36 F5 73 07 EC 07 DB B3 04 B6 F1 78 C1 AF 68  .6.s........x..h
0080  3E 3D B7 17 41 32 19 69 95 DB F6 72 1B 13 89 2A  >=..A2.i...r...*
0090  CF 46 8A 14 06 60 8E 95 FD 97 7A 3F 34 3D 18 B6  .F...`....z?4=..
00A0  1F 5D 77 E4 E7 9F A0 ED 5A 4B 5D 4B 57 C4 1A 29  .]w.....ZK]KW..)
00B0  E7 B7 FD 1E 9F 42 36 B0 BE ED FF 58 32 C3 6C E0  .....B6....X2.l.
00C0  CF 14 AA                                         ...

Command APDU : 00 B2 02 1C 00
Response APDU: 70 81 A3 9F 6E 0D 02 80 F0 01 22 09 92 00 39 89 74 19 66 93 81 90 06 8C 34 A1 42 BF A9 2B 88 FC 5D 86 AB 32 9C A8 19 DA E2 DF 38 85 F6 E1 4C 1B 8C CD 16 9F 58 F0 14 B9 3F 92 50 69 0C AC 6D 20 1F 9D 42 F3 00 B9 14 9C E4 C1 D1 6F FF 3B FB F5 F5 10 DC 6F A1 4F 9B F7 A3 8F BB 82 7F B5 18 FB 2C 00 6A 85 29 8B 84 1F 77 0F 3F 93 B8 33 9F 9F 83 63 6A 0C 49 88 4D 22 56 8F 32 70 E5 E0 7B F3 7F 77 58 5C C4 D4 B0 88 4C B0 24 3A 8C 3B 25 E8 85 AF EF 2E C3 2E CD 41 C7 44 DF AA 19 C7 30 2F 6F E0 4F 87 7F E5 90 00
Record No. 2
0000  70 81 A3 9F 6E 0D 02 80 F0 01 22 09 92 00 39 89  p...n....."...9.
0010  74 19 66 93 81 90 06 8C 34 A1 42 BF A9 2B 88 FC  t.f.....4.B..+..
0020  5D 86 AB 32 9C A8 19 DA E2 DF 38 85 F6 E1 4C 1B  ]..2......8...L.
0030  8C CD 16 9F 58 F0 14 B9 3F 92 50 69 0C AC 6D 20  ....X...?.Pi..m 
0040  1F 9D 42 F3 00 B9 14 9C E4 C1 D1 6F FF 3B FB F5  ..B........o.;..
0050  F5 10 DC 6F A1 4F 9B F7 A3 8F BB 82 7F B5 18 FB  ...o.O..........
0060  2C 00 6A 85 29 8B 84 1F 77 0F 3F 93 B8 33 9F 9F  ,.j.)...w.?..3..
0070  83 63 6A 0C 49 88 4D 22 56 8F 32 70 E5 E0 7B F3  .cj.I.M"V.2p..{.
0080  7F 77 58 5C C4 D4 B0 88 4C B0 24 3A 8C 3B 25 E8  .wX\....L.$:.;%.
0090  85 AF EF 2E C3 2E CD 41 C7 44 DF AA 19 C7 30 2F  .......A.D....0/
00A0  6F E0 4F 87 7F E5                                o.O...

Command APDU : 00 B2 01 24 00
Response APDU: 70 27 9F 47 01 03 9F 48 1A F2 17 AC 6F 17 6D FD 58 00 92 6C 10 A9 85 DD BF 7B 1C FF D8 27 D7 C4 82 14 13 9F 49 03 9F 37 04 90 00
Record No. 1
0000  70 27 9F 47 01 03 9F 48 1A F2 17 AC 6F 17 6D FD  p'.G...H....o.m.
0010  58 00 92 6C 10 A9 85 DD BF 7B 1C FF D8 27 D7 C4  X..l.....{...'..
0020  82 14 13 9F 49 03 9F 37 04                       ....I..7.

Command APDU : 00 B2 02 24 00
Response APDU: 70 81 94 9F 46 81 90 83 88 29 E4 97 9D 3A B9 7D 69 48 14 CE D3 C7 DC B3 51 83 08 D5 EA 4F 72 A7 CF 48 29 EF 14 94 FD 4D A6 40 31 3E D6 75 93 8A 40 E2 94 17 53 32 AD 6C 18 FA 04 A9 65 DC 36 FF 7E 7C 6E 26 68 F0 E0 D3 72 0F 19 EA 80 11 34 DF 7B 7F 32 98 BE DF 9C 54 5A 9D F8 E5 AB E9 71 2D F6 1E 52 90 28 18 64 5A C3 F8 37 AA CB 3B E7 C6 DD 45 FF F5 92 71 E8 66 B5 BB 27 32 01 0A 8D 90 D1 83 97 AB BF FC E3 A6 5D DD 83 07 FC 23 09 26 53 A7 7D 5B 28 64 12 90 00
Record No. 2
0000  70 81 94 9F 46 81 90 83 88 29 E4 97 9D 3A B9 7D  p...F....)...:.}
0010  69 48 14 CE D3 C7 DC B3 51 83 08 D5 EA 4F 72 A7  iH......Q....Or.
0020  CF 48 29 EF 14 94 FD 4D A6 40 31 3E D6 75 93 8A  .H)....M.@1>.u..
0030  40 E2 94 17 53 32 AD 6C 18 FA 04 A9 65 DC 36 FF  @...S2.l....e.6.
0040  7E 7C 6E 26 68 F0 E0 D3 72 0F 19 EA 80 11 34 DF  ~|n&h...r.....4.
0050  7B 7F 32 98 BE DF 9C 54 5A 9D F8 E5 AB E9 71 2D  {.2....TZ.....q-
0060  F6 1E 52 90 28 18 64 5A C3 F8 37 AA CB 3B E7 C6  ..R.(.dZ..7..;..
0070  DD 45 FF F5 92 71 E8 66 B5 BB 27 32 01 0A 8D 90  .E...q.f..'2....
0080  D1 83 97 AB BF FC E3 A6 5D DD 83 07 FC 23 09 26  ........]....#.&
0090  53 A7 7D 5B 28 64 12                             S.}[(d.

0000  57 13 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 D1 60 22 01 14 98  W.R4..P4.E.`"...
0010  19 09 04 00 0F 5A 08 52 34 00 00 50 34 11 45 5F  .....Z.R4..P4.E_
0020  24 03 16 02 28 5F 30 02 02 02 9F 44 01 02 5F 28  $...(_0....D.._(
0030  02 02 80 5F 34 01 04 8C 21 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F  ..._4...!.......
0040  1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 35  ...._*......7..5
0050  01 9F 45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 8D 0C 91 0A 8A 02  ..E..L..4.......
0060  95 05 9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...7..L.........
0070  00 00 5E 03 42 03 1F 03 9F 07 02 FF 00 9F 08 02  ..^.B...........
0080  00 02 9F 0D 05 B4 50 04 00 00 9F 0E 05 00 00 88  ......P.........
0090  00 00 9F 0F 05 B4 70 04 98 00 9F 42 02 09 78 9F  ......p....B..x.
00A0  4A 01 82                                         J..

------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<----------------------------Display Data Elements-----------------------------

Application Identifier (AID) - card: A000000000

Application Label: 454D562053696D756C61746F72 - EMV Simulator


Track 1 Data: 42353233343030303035303334313134355E202F2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020205E31363032323032343939323030333938393134393831303030373431393636

Track 2 Equivalent Data (Magnetic Strip): 
  Primary Account Number: 5234000050341145
  Expiration Date (YYMM): 1602
  Service Code: 201
  Discretionary Data: 1498190904000


Application Primary Account Number (PAN): 5234000050341145

Application Interchange Profile: 1980
  Byte 1: 
    Cardholder verification is supported (b5)
    Terminal risk management is to be performed (b4)
    CDA supported (b1)
  Byte 2: 
    RFU (b8)

Card Risk Management Data Object List 1 (CDOL1): 9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F37049F35019F45029F4C089F3403
  9f02 - 6 - Authorised amount of the transaction (excluding adjustments)
  9f03 - 6 - Secondary amount associated with the transaction representing a cashback amount
  9f1a - 2 - Terminal Country Code
  95 - 5 - Terminal Verification Results
  5f2a - 2 - Transaction Currency Code
  9a - 3 - Transaction Date
  9c - 1 - Transaction Type
  9f37 - 4 - Unpredictable Number
  9f35 - 1 - Terminal Type
  9f45 - 2 - Data Authentication Code
  9f4c - 8 - ICC Dynamic Number
  9f34 - 3 - Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results

Card Risk Management Data Object List 2 (CDOL2): 910A8A0295059F37049F4C08
  91 - 10 - Issuer Authentication Data
  8a - 2 - Authorisation Response Code
  95 - 5 - Terminal Verification Results
  9f37 - 4 - Unpredictable Number
  9f4c - 8 - ICC Dynamic Number

Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) List: 00000000000000005E0342031F03
  Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsucccessful
    Signature (paper)
  If terminal supports the CVM

  Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsucccessful
    Enciphered PIN verified online
  If terminal supports the CVM

  Fail cardholder verification if this CVM is unsuccessful
    No CVM required
  If terminal supports the CVM


Certification Authority Public Key Index: 04

Issuer Public Key Certificate: 27183B7E0B7DE447D9C52B5AD958CF4160FDC0A70D84C88AC9B01BB4B75861D836B18D154E2889EF50CCA83E7643B52791FF1CC61B1F0AD6161AF9E68E1436F57307EC07DBB304B6F178C1AF683E3DB7174132196995DBF6721B13892ACF468A1406608E95FD977A3F343D18B61F5D77E4E79FA0ED5A4B5D4B57C41A29E7B7FD1E9F4236B0BEEDFF5832C36CE0CF14AA

Issuer Public Key Remainder: 94EED18844B8C90A555CAE8B391686C12A30ED71C281D3FA90EEB05EAF298AE2C9D1400F

Signed Static Application Data: 068C34A142BFA92B88FC5D86AB329CA819DAE2DF3885F6E14C1B8CCD169F58F014B93F9250690CAC6D201F9D42F300B9149CE4C1D16FFF3BFBF5F510DC6FA14F9BF7A38FBB827FB518FB2C006A85298B841F770F3F93B8339F9F83636A0C49884D22568F3270E5E07BF37F77585CC4D4B0884CB0243A8C3B25E885AFEF2EC32ECD41C744DFAA19C7302F6FE04F877FE5

Application File Locator: 08010100100101011801020020010200
  SFI: 1
  First/Only Record Number: 1
  Last Record Number: 1
  Number of records involved in offline data authentication: 0

  SFI: 2
  First/Only Record Number: 1
  Last Record Number: 1
  Number of records involved in offline data authentication: 1

  SFI: 3
  First/Only Record Number: 1
  Last Record Number: 2
  Number of records involved in offline data authentication: 0

  SFI: 4
  First/Only Record Number: 1
  Last Record Number: 2
  Number of records involved in offline data authentication: 0


Application Expiration Date (YYMMDD): 160228

Issuer Country Code: 0280

Service Code: 202

Application Primary Account Number (PAN) Sequence Number: 04

Application Usage Control: FF00
  Byte 1:
    Valid at terminals other than ATMs
    Valid at ATMs
    Valid for international services
    Valid for domestic services
    Valid for international goods
    Valid for domestic goods
    Valid for international cash transactions
    Valid for domestic cash transactions
  Byte 2:

Application Version Number: 0002

Issuer Action Code - Default: B450040000
  Byte 1: 
    Offline data authentication was not performed (b8)
    ICC data missing (b6)
    Card appears on terminal exception file (b5)
    CDA failed (b3)
  Byte 2: 
    Expired application (b7)
    Requested service not allowed for card product (b5)
  Byte 3: 
    Online PIN entered (b3)
  Byte 4: 
  Byte 5: 

Issuer Action Code - Denial: 0000880000
  Byte 1: 
  Byte 2: 
  Byte 3: 
    Cardholder verification was not successful (b8)
    PIN entry required, PIN pad present, but PIN was not entered (b4)
  Byte 4: 
  Byte 5: 

Issuer Action Code - Online: B470049800
  Byte 1: 
    Offline data authentication was not performed (b8)
    ICC data missing (b6)
    Card appears on terminal exception file (b5)
    CDA failed (b3)
  Byte 2: 
    Expired application (b7)
    Application not yet effective (b6)
    Requested service not allowed for card product (b5)
  Byte 3: 
    Online PIN entered (b3)
  Byte 4: 
    Transaction exceeds floor limit (b8)
    Transaction selected randomly for online processing (b5)
    Merchant forced transaction online (b4)
  Byte 5: 

Issuer Public Key Exponent: 03

Application Currency Code: 0978

Application Currency Exponent: 02

ICC Public Key Certificate: 838829E4979D3AB97D694814CED3C7DCB3518308D5EA4F72A7CF4829EF1494FD4DA640313ED675938A40E294175332AD6C18FA04A965DC36FF7E7C6E2668F0E0D3720F19EA801134DF7B7F3298BEDF9C545A9DF8E5ABE9712DF61E52902818645AC3F837AACB3BE7C6DD45FFF59271E866B5BB2732010A8D90D18397ABBFFCE3A65DDD8307FC23092653A77D5B286412

ICC Public Key Exponent: 03

ICC Public Key Remainder: F217AC6F176DFD5800926C10A985DDBF7B1CFFD827D7C4821413

Dynamic Data Authentication Data Object List (DDOL): 9F3704
  9f37 - 4 - Unpredictable Number

Static Data Authentication Tag List: 82

Track 1 Bit Map for CVC3 (Paypass): 0000000001C0

Track 1 Bit Map for UN and ATC (Paypass): 000000078000

Track 1 Number of ATC Digits (Paypass): 02

Track 2 Bit Map for CVC3 (Paypass): 00E0

Track 2 Bit Map for UN and ATC (Paypass): 001E

Track 2 Number of ATC Digits (Paypass): 02

Track 2 Data (Paypass): 5234000050341145D16022021498100004000F

Mag Stripe Application Version Number (Card) (Paypass): 0001

Third Party Data: 0280F001220992003989741966

------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
```